# Why the need to hide identities in '3rd Rock from the Sun'

Tags: third-rock-from-the-sun

As shown in the pilot episode, the entire Solomon family has simply *occupied* the bodies of four human beings. And clearly they are shown to be extremely smart.

Since the bodies belong to human beings, there should be no need for the Solomons to be worried about someone finding out about their real identities. So why are they?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

They didn't occupy actual human bodies. They picked their bodies out in a catalog and are wearing them like a skin.

The reason for the secret identities is because the skins they chose don't have actual human histories. Though they do find out later that they have some "relatives" that some of the people believe are theirs simply by name and the fact that they look *similar* to some other humans.

Comment: Subtle, yet important point, THanks